# Retrieve my number after make it in Byte[]

Tags: java

I want to retrieve a basic number after make it in Byte[]

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           LinkedList<Byte> s1 = new LinkedList<Byte>();
           String a = "0.111112345";
           for (byte bb : a.getBytes()) {
                s1.add(bb);
            }
 //how to retrieve "0.111112345"; from s1 ?
```

}

Retrieve my number after make it in Byte[] ?

Comment: Stepping back a second, what's the purpose of this exercise? I don't see much use in getting an int representation of the first 4 bytes of a string.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What about [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using `Byte[]` in place of `byte[]`:

```
    byte[] t = (byte[]) s1.subList(0, 3).toArray();
    System.out.println(convertByteToInt(t));
```

Also You may want to use `parse()` to convert string to numbers e.g. below:

```
    String intString= new String(t); //<--get String from byte array
    int numInt = Integer.parseInt(intString);
```

Comment: @Geoff_Montee: I already updated the answer to convert the substring.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee Ooops.. I had several variations initially with double, int conversions. Then mixed the answer from them. Corrected. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

A `Byte[]` is not a `byte[]`, but you don't need to use the linked list and sublist, you could do it purely with `byte[]`, something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  String a = "0.111112345";
  byte[] allBytes = a.getBytes("UTF-8");
  byte[] t = Arrays.copyOf(allBytes, 4);
  System.out.println(convertByteToInt(t));
}
```

`java.util.Arrays.copyOf` returns a copy of the initial segment of the given array truncated or extended with zeroes to the given length.

This should print the result `808333617`, which is the decimal representation of hex `302E3131` (the UTF-8 bytes of the characters zero, dot, one, one).

Comment: It works but it dosnot give to me a correcte number xD 
i have : 808333617 as result :(

Comment: @Mehdi What did you expect it to do?

Comment: a hope to retreive `111112345` which is in number `0.111112345`

Comment: @Mehdi then you need to parse the string. The byte array that's returned from getBytes() is a low-level representation of the *characters* in the string, not the *numbers* that those characters depict.

Comment: @Mehdi in which case you probably want to use `Integer.parseInt(a.substring(a.indexOf(".") + 1))` (which will find the first dot, take all the following characters and then parse them as an integer). This will work up to `<something>.2147483647`, as 2147483647 is the maximum value an `int` can hold.  If you need more than that use `long` or `BigInteger` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, i edited my question. in my example i have just `a` but in my algorithm i have juste Byte[] of `a` an i must to retreive `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Re-write this line:

```
Byte[] t = (Byte[]) s1.subList(0, 3).toArray();
```

as following:

```
Byte[] t = s1.subList(0, 3).toArray(new Byte[3]);
```

Method `toArray()` return `Object[]`. However method `toArray(array)` returns array passed to it as a parameter or, if this array is not long enough, other array of the same type.

Comment: Also going to have problems because the result gets passed to a method expecting an array of primitive bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Byte[] t = s1.subList(0, 3).toArray(new Byte[3]);
Then, look this BigInteger constructor [public BigInteger(byte[] val)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Then, use:
[int intValue();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue%28%29)